# Lifecycle hook of AfterViewInit in Jasmine test

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am confused on lifecycle hooks in relationship with Jasmine testing.  The LifeCycle Angular doc does not mention testing https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks.  The testing doc only mentions OnChange https://angular.io/guide/testing.
I have a sample component as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-prod-category-detail',
  templateUrl: './prod-category-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./prod-category-detail.component.css']
})
//
export class ProdCategoryDetailComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
    ...
    nav: HTMLSelectElement;
    //
    constructor(
        ...
        private _elementRef: ElementRef ) { }
    ...
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log( 'ProdCategoryDetailComponent: ngAfterViewInit' );
        this.nav = this._elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#nav');
    }
    ...
}
```

As a note, this is an Angular CLI app with the latest downloads.  In Karma, I do not see the console log, therefore ***nav*** is never set.  I am currently invoking it in my spec as follows:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProdCategoryDetailComponent);
  sut = fixture.componentInstance;
  sut.ngAfterViewInit( );
  fixture.detectChanges( );
});
```

### Is this proper way of handling this?

For shusson this is from some time ago and I have not looked at this for some time.  Hope it will help.  Note, I am using Primeface primeng library:

```
describe('ProdCategoryDetailComponent', () => {
  let sut: ProdCategoryDetailComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture< ProdCategoryDetailComponent >;
  let alertService: AlertsService;
  let prodCatService: ProdCategoryServiceMock;
  let confirmService: ConfirmationServiceMock;
  let elementRef: MockElementRef;
  //
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        ButtonModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        ProdCategoryDetailComponent,
        AlertsComponent,
        ConfirmDialog
      ],
      providers: [
        AlertsService,
        { provide: ProdCategoryService, useClass: ProdCategoryServiceMock },
        { provide: MockBackend, useClass: MockBackend },
        { provide: BaseRequestOptions, useClass: BaseRequestOptions },
        { provide: ConfirmationService, useClass: ConfirmationServiceMock },
        { provide: ElementRef, useClass: MockElementRef }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
  //
  beforeEach(inject([AlertsService, ProdCategoryService,
      ConfirmationService, ElementRef],
        (srvc: AlertsService, pcsm: ProdCategoryServiceMock,
        cs: ConfirmationServiceMock, er: MockElementRef) => {
    alertService = srvc;
    prodCatService = pcsm;
    confirmService = cs;
    elementRef = er;
  }));
  //
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProdCategoryDetailComponent);
    sut = fixture.componentInstance;
    sut.ngAfterViewInit( );
    fixture.detectChanges( );
  });
  //
```

Comment: ngAfterViewInit should be called once with the first fixture.detectChanges( );

Comment: Can you show us how you configure the TestBed?
 e.g `TestBed.configureTestingModule(...)`. Also do you actually have any tests? Without an `it` test, `beforeEach` will not be called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I often directly call the life cycle hooks from each spec whenever necessary. And this works. 
Because this gives the flexibility to manipulate any data before calling `ngAfterViewInit()` or `ngOnInit()`.

I have also seen few angular libraries test spec using it in the same way. For eg, check this [videogular](https://github.com/videogular/videogular2/blob/master/src/controls/vg-controls.spec.ts#L60) spec file. So there is no harm in calling those methods manually.

Also copying the same code here, just to avoid the link to be broken in future.

```
it('Should hide controls after view init', () => {
        spyOn(controls, 'hide').and.callFake(() => {});

        controls.vgAutohide = true;

        controls.ngAfterViewInit();

        expect(controls.hide).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't directly call the life cycle hooks from spec but we can the call custom methods. Because for calling lifecycle books we need to create an instance of the component using fixture.

**Example: In my example, I need to set padding-left, and right to 0 as bootstrap gives some padding left and right by default So I need to remove it.**

HTML File - app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('navCol', { static: true }) navCol: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.navCol.nativeElement, 'padding-left', '0px');
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.navCol.nativeElement, 'padding-right', '0px');
  }
}
```

app.component.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  it('should load page and remove padding', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.componentInstance.ngAfterViewInit();
    const styles = window.getComputedStyle(fixture.nativeElement);

    expect(styles.paddingLeft).toBe('0px');
    expect(styles.paddingRight).toBe('0px');
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Sahil Shikalgar, how is the view child not giving you a problem in this situation, and you are saying you don't have to call fixture.ngAfterViewInit();

Comment: Thanks, @Sahil Shikalgar, I think I was using fixture.detectChanges(), even though my test was not asserting the HTML. I think perhaps most people use fixture.detectChanges() more often than they have to.

Comment: Thanks Girum, I will also check with fixture.detectChanges() instead of doing manual call.