# How to test a subscription with a plain subject in service

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, karma-runner, subject

I want to test a component, which has a subscription to a subject in a service.

Component subscribes:

```
let x: string[] = [];

public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.subscription = this.service.observer$.subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.x = data.value;
    ...
  }
}
```

The Service has the Subject property:

```
public observer$: Subject<any>;
```

In the testcase, I try to setup that as follows:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Service);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

it('should get a subscription event', () => {
    const response: any[] = [];
    service.observer$ = new Subject<any>();
    service.observer$.next(['some content']);

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.x.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);

  });
```

This does not work. x remains empty.

Can anyone provide the proper way to test this? I saw some examples, where the service provides a method for observer.new() where the tester then spies on that one. But no example on how to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

[AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) only triggers ones per initialization.
Therefore your second `fixture.detectChanges()` doesnt trigger it again.
You need to remove the `fixture.detectChanges()` in the `beforeEach`

Something like this

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Service);
  });

it('should get a subscription event', () => {
    const response: any[] = [];
    service.observer$ = new Subject<any>();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    service.observer$.next(['some content']);
    expect(component.x.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);

  });
```

Comment: Please ignore the detectChanges method. This should not be relevant to this question. The issue is that it seems that the component does not receive the event here afaik. Nevertheless, I tried to remove detectChanges in beforeEach, but that gave me only lifecycle errors while running the testcase.

Comment: going though this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45038645/lifecycle-hook-of-afterviewinit-in-jasmine-test?rq=1) it appears that `ngAfterViewInit` need to be called manually. Try to call it before you use `.next()`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help either. I tried with a variable which has been set in AfterViewInit, this was correctly set, so it was called. Thanks for trying to help. I suppose the coupling with the service does not seem correct.